# Jrebel - use license on the remote server

Tags: jrebel

I have JRebel 5.2.0 and activated it trough Eclipse JRebel Config Center using license code. It activated successfully and Open Source Software Plan is active.

On the same OS, I have a virtual machine running with Glassfish server and I would like to use it as a Remote Server, but it also requires license.

Is it possible to use the same license on the virtual machine? I was not able to find jrebel.lic file under ~/.jrebel directory.

Comment: If you didn't find your license file in ~/.jrebel directory, where is your licenses then?

Comment: License file doesn't appear event if I activate it without Eclipse (using java -jar jrebel.jar --activate). I think it stores information about license activation in different place.

Comment: Do you use my.jrebel.com as a license provider?

Comment: Yes, I do. I can see following URL in jrebel logs: my.jrebel.com:443

Comment: There's no license file create in case my.jrebel.com. You can try activating JRebel from the command line at the remote machine - that should work fine.

Comment: Will two licenses be used?

Comment: Most likely yes. But my.jrebel.com allows that.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need a licence. Just enable "Jrebel Remoting" in your eclipse project and it will generate a "key".
Just pack the key together with your webapp (war) and install it on your remote server.

Answer (score -1):

By https://my.jrebel.com, register a account, then you have a license code in https://my.jrebel.com/account/how-to-activate.